# Python Gurobi: MIP best objective and bound output with respect runtime

Tags: python, gurobi

I am using Gurobi to solve a max MIP via Python. I would like to graph the change in best objective value (lower bound) and bound (upper bound) with respect to runtime (like picture below). Is there any way that I could collect these information/graph the result directly while Gurobi is optimizing? Thank you very much!

[image]

Best,
Grace

Answer (score 1):

This same question was answered on the [Gurobi community forum](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360071330032). You can do this with a callback. For example, the code below uses a callback to extract incumbent objective values, best bounds, and runtimes. These values are stored in a list. After the optimization completes, the values are written to a CSV file.

```
import gurobipy as gp
import csv
import time


def data_cb(model, where):
    if where == gp.GRB.Callback.MIP:
        cur_obj = model.cbGet(gp.GRB.Callback.MIP_OBJBST)
        cur_bd = model.cbGet(gp.GRB.Callback.MIP_OBJBND)

        # Did objective value or best bound change?
        if model._obj != cur_obj or model._bd != cur_bd:
            model._obj = cur_obj
            model._bd = cur_bd
            model._data.append([time.time() - m._start, cur_obj, cur_bd])

# Build model m here

m._obj = None
m._bd = None
m._data = []
m._start = time.time()
m.optimize(callback=data_cb)

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(m._data)
```